# exists a "two-factor authentication" for sudo, if not how to make one anyway?

Tags: sudo, authentication

**tl;dr** normaly to gain root priviledges via `sudo` requires a special user account and the use of its passphrase as means to authetication. Due to keylogging/replay (in X.org session) attacks, I would like to add another security layer (e.g. the requirement for an usb dongle to be present). Is this possible?

**long version**
I know that being root can be dangerous, yet occasionally I do a `sudo -i` for some tasks that I have not setup to work without root priveleges. Being lazy I often do this inside a X.org session and the problem is that the else somewhat castrated/sandboxed webbrowser could read my user passphrase. With this passphrase priveledge escalation is possible via `sudo`. I would like to mitigate this by only allowing the use of `sudo` when another second factor of authentication is present (a hardware triggered one, as to prevent a software only attack). Therefore my question.

Using udev I could update/adjust the /etc/sudoers file accordingly (i.e. dynamically at my user to the sudoers when usb dongle present). My **question is** if there is a more straightforward way to do it. My reading of `man sudo` did not provide me with any, but maybe there is a way.

Clarification: I know that many types of keyloggers are evidence that the box is owned and lost anyway. I ask here because I argue that X.org Gui applications are somewhat at liberty to sniff each others keyboard input hence preventing me to use `sudo` inside an X.org session.

Comment: Yes, buy a yubikey and check out u2f, a 2 factor standard developed by big names in the business and it's open. Works well with git, Gmail and SSH

Comment: @Torxed seems interesting, as at least on the yubiley promo website they mention "our free open source software". Since its a dedicated hardware and I take it that the 40$ price buys me some intergration into `sudo` that goes beyond what I have suggested. Have to find out if it is a using kernel modules. Anyway my question was not as much about hardware availability, but the way to setup the `/etc/sudoers` config file for two factor authentication

Comment: You could integrate Google's 2fa (which would then use your phone as the second factor), some people have done it for logins, ssh, etc.  https://www.sudo.ws/pipermail/sudo-users/2011-September/004814.html - someone could write up a summary of that as an answer.

Comment: It does not utilize kernel modules, it does however require a u2f server (also open source) to be present. If you don't mind Google and Yubikey offer these for free as well. You can get a Yubikey for less than $12 if you just look around. I own two personally so I might be swaying to their side but I have no affiliation with them (I guess all spy's would say this heh). But it's a truly good product, robust as hell (drove over it with my car and washed it on numerous occasions). Even my mother uses one so it's quite easy to use tbh. Well worth experimenting with at least.

Comment: @EightBitTony yes that would be somewhat of a response to my question. If I had a wish I would like to use a mere usb dongle (like a flash drive) and a second factor that is less dependent on a second party (especially business stuff like commercial .... no google). If I come as to write a `udev` based way to add this two-factor via a flash drive. I will post the info as an answer to question myself.

Comment: This is not unique to Xorg but simply the classic Unix user model - any process running as your user id could use the debugger interfaces to monitor your process, open the tty's assigned to you, etc.

Comment: @alanc you opened my eyes more. I thought only the infamous `xinput test $(keyboardnum)` allowing to sniff within a Xorg session was problem. But as you helped me see, it is sadly not only Xorg that has a challange, as with the classic user model (classic = time without malware?) one could use `strace -p $pidOfattackedOtherTtyProcess` or `cat /proc/$pid/$filenameForPrivateInfo` and attack/sniff user input also on ttys. And I fooled myself thinking thought linux highlights security, stupid me